# Dropdown shows inside navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm making navbar and sidebar with Bootstrap using their example.
Dropdown in navbar shows inside of it instead of showing below it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="#">
        <img src="/www/images/ccg_logo.png" height="32">
    </a>
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <img height="32" class="rounded-circle" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/451779815415218177/cf8af4140a2870e1266446d07fa003cf.png">               Your Nightmare
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">

                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> Settings</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-palette"></i> Appearance</a>

                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/www/login/logout"><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i> Log out</a>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

https://jsfiddle.net/asv4z6jx/
```

Right side of image:
[image: dropdown on right is inside navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this rule to your css file

```
 .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute!important;
    }
```